# Get last occurrence for the string after '/' in redshift

Tags: sql, string, amazon-redshift

I am fairly new to regex expressions and always had a trouble to follow. It would be really helpful if I can get answer to the following problem.

I have a column with strings in redshift table and want to extract a certain part of the string(The string that is after the last '/'). For example, I have `https://hello.com/my_first_website` in my redshift table with the column name as `customer_site`, from this I want to extract `my_first_website` as output. Can someone tell me a regex expression that can help me to extract this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`regexp_substr`**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html) function such as

```
SELECT regexp_substr('https://hello.com/my_first_website','[^/]*$')
```